# Javers - foreign key constraint fails with mysql

Tags: foreign-keys, sqlexception, audit-trail, javers

I am new in javers. Started a POC for my application but getting SQL_EXCEPTION while committing, due to 'last_insert_id()' function of mysql returns '0'.

What I did:

- Added started in spring boot maven (javers core & javers mysql)
- Created a connection with my database schema
- Got all the tables in may db (jv_global_id, jv_commit etc..)

Problem:

> I am using spring boot 2.0 with mysql version 5.7 I debugged the
>   problem in deep and found that When Javers code
>   'org.javers.repository.sql.session.Session.java' method
>   'executeInsertAndGetSequence' line no 40, tries to find primary key it
>   return as zero '0'.  As per code, mysql dialect does not support
>   sequences so it generate a value from keyGenerator using mysql funtion
>   'last_insert_id()' at eventually it returns zero.

I got following error:

```
SQL_EXCEPTION: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jv_snapshot`, CONSTRAINT `jv_snapshot_commit_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`commit_fk`) REFERENCES `jv_commit` (`commit_pk`))\nwhile executing sql: INSERT INTO thinkhr_portal.jv_snapshot ( type, global_id_fk, commit_fk, version, state, changed_properties, managed_type ) VALUES  ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,? )
```

I wonder, if javers does not support mysql version 5.7 or there is something else I need to take care in my javers configuration.

Comment: @Bartek Walacik Can you please answer.

Comment: How did you configured your JaversRepository? Did you set the right dialect?

Comment: Yes I did, I used artifactId "javers-persistence-sql" with version 5.6.0 with mysql connector version as 5.1.44

Comment: But which dialect did you choose?

Comment: I used mysql dialect. My spring boot application finds appropriate dialect based on the given JDBC url in configuration properties.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, and it was due to creating a new connection every time in the ConnectionProvider. Javers was trying to get the commit id by running `select last_insert_id()`, and in the new connection, it always returns 0.

You want your connection provider to be something like this:

```
        ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = new ConnectionProvider() {
            private Connection conn;
            @Override
            public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
                if (conn == null) {
                    conn = buildNewConnection();
                }
                return conn;
            }
        };
```